Example for $X$ not Banach but $X^*$ is reflexive

Example for $X$ not Banach but $X^*$ is reflexive

I had a a problem showing that if $X$ is Banach then $X^*$ reflexive means $X$ is reflexive.
Now the second part is asking if $X$ is not Banach and $X^*$ is reflexive, does it hold that $X$ is reflexive?
I saw on a different post that I need to show $c_{00}^*=\ell_2$ with $\ell_2$ norm but I havn't manage to prove it.

Necessary for what? How can $X$ be reflexive if it is not Banach? As for your example: take e.g. $X=$ some non-complete prehilbert space.

For your example, $X$ would be incomplete and dense in its completion $Y$, and then $X^* = Y^$.  So if, for example, $Y=L^2$ we get $Y^$ reflexive,

@GEdgar I'm now thinking about what the first comment said. That if I assume X is not banach, then there is no way X is reflexive immediately because X is isomorphic to $X^{**}$ which is complete.

I have provided an answer to this question here. Perhaps you can take a look at that and ask if you have any questions about the reasoning there. I can add more details to the other answer if they are required.

Correct.  If $X$ incomplete then $X$ is not reflexive.  But the OP says $X^*$ should be reflexive.  So this answers "second part".
